# how to access objects method in a event bind

Tags: javascript

```js
(function() {
  let create = {

    init() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvent();
    },

    bindEvent() {
      $(this.$content_buttons).click(function() {
        create.preformAction(this);
      });
    },

    cacheDom() {
      this.$content_buttons = $('.content_button');
    },

    preformAction(el) {
      alert('its class is ' + $(el).attr('class'));
    }
  };
  create.init();
}());
```

consider my code above I am able to access **performAction** method of **create** object by doing this **create.performAction** . is there any other way of doing. thanks in advance.

Comment: `bindEvent() {
            $(this.$content_buttons).click((e) => this.preformAction(e.target));
        },`

Comment: @zeeeuu,please check the answer.if it's correct check it as true,thanks

Answer (score 2):

try it:

```js
(function() {
 let create = {

init() {
  this.cacheDom();
  this.bindEvent();
},

bindEvent() {

  $(this.$content_buttons).click(function() {
    create.preformAction(this);
  });
},

cacheDom() {
  this.$content_buttons = $('.content_button');
},

preformAction(el) {
  alert('its class is ' + $(el).attr('class'));
}
 };
  create.init();
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="content_button class1">click1</button>
<button class="content_button class2">click2</button>
```